# How do I select a node only when the other node satisfies a condition

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

```
<div class="apoSoftKpiBox concrete">
  <div class="apoBoxIconBar">
    <div class="apoKpiBoxTop">
      <h4 class="ng-binding">Development</h4>
    </div>
   <div class="apoKpiBoxBottom">
    <div class="col-xs-12 apoKpiBoxValue shortNumber ng-binding">   0 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the node apoKpiBoxBottom but to do so, the first node apoKpiBoxTop should have the text "Development" first

I use this to select both elements

```
//div/h4[contains(text(),'Development')]|//div[contains(text(),'0')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible XPath based on your attempted XPath and the HTML snippet posted :

```
//div[div/h4[contains(.,'Development')]]/div[@class='apoKpiBoxBottom']/div
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/C6x21w-k6)</kbd>**

Comment: what is the dot for in [contains(.,'Development')]?

Answer (score 0):

Below should work:

```
//div[@class="apoKpiBoxTop" and .="Development"]/following-sibling::div[@class="apoKpiBoxBottom"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `xpath`

```
//div[@class='apoKpiBoxTop']/h4[contains(text(), 'Development')]/following::div[@class='apoKpiBoxBottom']
```

OR

```
//div[@class='apoKpiBoxTop']/h4[contains(text(), 'Development')]/..//following-sibling::div[@class='apoKpiBoxBottom']
```